# Share realm object with other devices

Tags: ios, realm

Is it possible to share realm objects across iOS devices?
I'm creating an app that has Ticket objects in Realm and I'd like to be able to share those objects with others (who would also need to have the app).

How would one go about this?

Comment: You can not do this with Realm alone. Realm is a local ORM solution and not a cloud. You will need to use a cloud service like iCloud or Firebase to put the data you want to share in a server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**, Realm Mobile Platform allows you to store data locally as well as  in the cloud. Synchronization and conflict resolution are all automatic. You can also create public Realms (global tables accessible by all users) as well as shared Realms (user tables where you can give reading, writing or admin rights to specific users). If you want to share all Tickets to all users, a global /Ticket table would be a good choice.

**No**, current version doesn't support fine-grained access control, that is access rights per object inside a Realm. You must share the whole Realm and all its objects. I look forward to using this important, missing feature.

---

https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/releases